# How to embed an application into another application dynamically?

Tags: user-interface, widget, tiling

I want to build a [general purpose application that will be used like a IDE for anything](https://github.com/ceremcem/creat-ide).

How can I embed an application into another application, in the runtime, like so:

[image]

Comment: You may want to specify the base environment (Linux, Windows, Mac OS). If you are using Linux, you could use XEmbed to embed X applications inside your own application.

Comment: Yes, the primary platform is Linux. I'll look at XEmbed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish what you want.

In the comments, you said your target platform is Linux. Using [XEmbed](http://standards.freedesktop.org/xembed-spec/xembed-spec-latest.html) ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XEmbed)) lets you embed X applications inside another application. I have never used it personally so I cannot comment on how easy to use or stable it is as a solution to your problem.

At another level, you could implement what you are seeking as an extension to a window manager. [Xmonad](http://xmonad.org/tour.html) comes to mind as an extensible window manager: you could add a hook that tells Xmonad how to handle your windows. This requires knowledge of Xmonad and Haskell, though.